# TCPDF: How to calculate and fit proper block on one page and then start next with table

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

I am using tcpdf for the very first time and with the help of their documentation, i am able to create the content with the help of table. I can not show you the design but will try to explain.

left side is one image and right side one image and in the middle total of 4 contents are about to visible. sometimes, out of these 4 contents, 1 might not present. These content is dynamic and can be from 1 to 100 to 200 blocks.

I created `<table>` with one `<tr>` and three `<td>` and this is into for loop. Issue is last content on first page is breaking and continue on second which is not showing good. What I want is whatever number of block is fitting onto the first page, should be on first page and then further create another page and continue printing blocks onto them and so on.

Here is my code

```
$A4Ht = 210; //210 mm A4 page width 
$A4Ht = 297; //297 mm A4 page height

$margin = 15;//margin from all side before pdf starts 
$x1 = 15; //pdf starts from this x point
$x2 = 160; // event map starts from this x point
$pdfWidth = 200;

$this->load->library("tcpdf/tcpdf");
$pdf = new Tcpdf('P', 'mm', 'A4', true, 'UTF-8', false);

$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
$pdf->SetMargins($margin, $margin, $margin,true);       // LEFT, TOP, RIGHT, BOTTOM
$pdf->setPageOrientation("P",true,$margin);

$pdf->SetTitle("Title");
$pdf->SetAuthor("Author");
$pdf->AddPage('P', 'A4');
$pdf->setPage(1, true);
$pdf->Image("logo.png",$x1,5,60,10.412,"png",'','',true,320);

$tbl = '<table style="background-color:#eee;"><tr><td width="4%"></td><td width="90%"><table><tr style="line-height:20px;"><td></td></tr></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" style="margin-top:25px;">';
for($p=0;$p<$Count;$p++){
    $image1 = "123.jpg";
    $image2 = "456.jpg";

    $title1 = "dynamic";
    $title2 = "dynamic";
    $title3 = "dynamic";
    $title4 = "dynamic";

        $addTitle1 = '<table cellpadding="2"><tr><td valign="top" width="5%"></td><td width="90%">'.$title1.'</td></tr></table>';
        $addTitle2 = '<table cellpadding="2"><tr><td valign="top" width="5%"></td><td width="90%">'.$title2.'</td></tr></table>';
        $addTitle3 = '<table cellpadding="2"><tr><td valign="top" width="5%"></td><td width="90%">'.$title3.'</td></tr></table>';
    $addTitle4 = '<table cellpadding="2"><tr><td valign="top" width="5%"></td><td valign="top" width="8%"><img width="100" src="'.$pathWeb.'/icon.png" /></td ><td valign="middle" width="82%">&nbsp;'.$title4.'</td></tr></table>';        
    $tbl.='<tr>
                <td width="25%"><img src="'.$image1.'" width="140" height="105"></td>
                <td width="46%">
                        <tr><td style="font-family:AvenirNext-Bold;color:#000;font-size:14px;line-height:15px;">'.$addTitle1.'</td></tr>
                        <tr><td style="font-family:AvenirNext-Bold;color:#0096ff;font-size:10px;">'.$addTitle2.'</td></tr>
                        <tr><td style="font-family:AvenirNext-DemiBold;color:#000;font-size:6px;">'.$addTitle3.'</td></tr>
                        <tr><td style="font-family:AvenirNext-DemiBold;color:#000;font-size:9px;">'.$addTitle4.'</td></tr>
                </td>
                <td width="29%"><img src="'.$image2.'" width="160" height="100"></td>
        </tr>';
}
$tbl.='</table><table><tr style="line-height:20px;"><td></td></tr></table></td><td width="4%"></td></tr></table>';

$tbl=utf8_encode($tbl);
$pdf->writeHTML($tbl, true, false, false, false, '');
```

I am unable to break the page and continue on second page. some blocks are half on first and rest on second. few blocks are 95% on first page and rest on second. how do i go ahead of this.

Comment: As I experienced writeHTML() method does not support all the html styles and attributes. It becomes frustrating in some point. Instead of that use the code in [example_011](https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_011) in TCPDF official page. It should break the page if needed but also you can use $pdf->AddPage(); to trigger if you use this example.

Comment: example doesn't demonstrate breaking of page or table. I can user addPage() but how do i calculate that this is the point where i need to break it and send it to the second page.

Comment: There is a different technique in example_011 other than rendering HTML with writeHTML() method. In this case you can use AddPage(), but it is optional because TCPDF adds page break if it is necessary.

Comment: page is breaking automatically. Problem is my content. I have to check that on every page last block should be complete and it should not break.

Comment: How do I know that my table is reached end of first page?